# Using BeatifulSoup, how do I get content with find_all?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

HTML:

```
<meta name="speaker" content="Peter">
<meta name="speaker" content="John">
<meta name="speaker" content="Jim">
```

Usually if I want to get only the content I use

```
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup

name = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'speaker'})['content']

print(name)
```

The output would be `Peter`

But if I want to get every name I cannot use

```
name = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'name': 'speaker'})['content']
```

since the square brackets only supports an integer when using find_all.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

```
names = soup.find_all('meta', attrs={'name': 'speaker'})
```

You can use for loop

```
name_list = []
for name in names:
    name_list.append(name["content"])
```

or list comprehension

```
name_list = [name["content"] for name in names]
```

then you get

```
['Peter', 'John', 'Jim']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It´s actually much simpler than I thought!